# Swift 4 - Filtering Array with Array

Tags: swift, swift4, higher-order-functions

I have a list of entries, that have an id, and I want to filter them down to ones that have an entry.id matching one of the ids in selectedIDs. Is there a way to do this with filter or do I have to use a for loop?

```
struct Entry {
    let id: String
}
var allEntries = [Entry]()
var selectedIDs = [String]
```

e.g.

```
allEntries = [Entry(id: "1"), Entry(id:"2"), Entry(id:"3"), Entry(id:"4")]
selectedIDs = ["1", "3"]

// return selectedEntries
var selectedEntries = [Entry(id: "1"), Entry(id: "3")]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with Rakesha Shastri's answer. For performance reasons, you may want to make `selectedIDs` a `Set` instead of an `Array`:

```
let allEntries = [Entry(id: "1"), Entry(id:"2"), Entry(id:"3"), Entry(id:"4")]
let selectedIDs: Set<String> = ["1", "3"]
let selectedEntries = allEntries.filter({ selectedIDs.contains($0.id) })
```

The reason is that searching an `Array` has a computational complexity of `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the array, while searching a `Set` (i.e. a hash table) is `O(1)` *on average*.

- If you keep `selectedIDs` as array, the overall solution has a complexity of `O(n * m)` where `n` and `m` are the lengths of `selectedIDs` and `allEntries`, respectively.
- If you use `Set`, the overall complexity reduces to `O(m)`.

Having said that, your example is too trivial for either methods to make a difference.

Answer (score 4):

Filter `allEntries` based on whether `selectedIDs` contains `id`.

```
var allEntries = [Entry(id: "1"), Entry(id:"2"), Entry(id:"3"), Entry(id:"4")]
var selectedIDs = ["1", "3"]

var selectedEntries = allEntries.filter({ selectedIDs.contains($0.id) })
```

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity, if say selectedIDs were another type of struct with IDs as a property, how would this change the selectedIDs.contains($0.id) part?

Comment: `map` then `filter`

Comment: @user3628240 like Ashley said, you map the struct array to a string array and then do the filtering.

Comment: Contains(where:) would be more appropriate https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2297359-contains

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map(*:)*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map) and [filter(:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994718-filter) to achieve this

```
let matchingEntries = allEntries.map({$0.id}).filter({selectedIDs.contains($0)})
```

**.map** will return you just id's as an array, then **.filter** will filter them with the **selectedIDs**

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.5:**

```
let filteredArray = array.filter { self.selectedIDs.map(\.id).contains($0.id) }
```